# Angular read component name from json and add 'this' to the name

Tags: angular, angular13

I am trying to get a name of a component from a json file and via a method add `'this'` to its name.

```
import { MyComponent } from './Mycomponent';

...

MyComponent = MyComponent;


data = [
    {
      "name": "MyComponent"
    }
  ];
```

The method:

```
  test(name: any) {
    return this.[name];
  }
```

usage example:

```
this.test('MyComponent');
```

Expected output is:

```
this.MyComponent
```

When I try: `this.[name]`

I get Identifier expected.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I dont udnerstand what is the expected outcome nor what is actual behavior.

Comment: It would be better if you would just show us the expected outcome instead of describing it.

Comment: I input this: this.test('MyComponent'); and the expected outcome is: this.MyComponent

Comment: edit the post please. Is expected output a json as well, a string? a method call? I hve no idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to something like this, for example:

**TS**

```
componentName: any;

  data = [
    {
      name: 'MyComponent',
    },
  ];

  test(name: any) {
    this.componentName = `this.${name}`; // storing this.Mycomponent name to variable for displaying 
    return `this.${name}`;
  }

  testbtnHandle() {
    this.test('MyComponent');   // it will call the test function with MyComponent name parameter
  }
```

**HTML**

```
{{componentName}} // for display


<button type="button" (click)="testbtnHandle()">click</button>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nbwfbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you can check or play with code.

Comment: I get: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.

Comment: can you add some more information or code in your question or post so it will be easy to understand

Comment: I've updated the question with more code

Comment: please make a [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/)